# How to pass imageInByte in an intent and convert it?

Tags: android

In main activity I select an image from gallery with the below code

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setType("image/*");
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

useally I insert it to sqlite db directly in my `main_activity` with the  below code

```
 Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
               // convert bitmap to byte
               ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
               byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
               Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
               // Inserting Contacts
               Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
              db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte));
```

.. but I want to pass the image to another activity to add discreption to it.

I am receiving the intent in another activity like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
          DBhelper db = new DBhelper(this);

           db.addContact(new Contact("add", intent));
```

so I want to be pass `imageInByte` through an intent. but my problem in the another activity I cannot insert intent type.
how to fix that ?

Comment: You mean you want to get the Bitmap in your other activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the Bitmap in another activity, then do this

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Also, don't forget to pass the byteArray from your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image",imageInByte);
```

Comment: then simply I add it like this               db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte)); ?

Comment: If you want to insert imageInByte itself then you don't need to convert it back to bitmap. You can simply insert it after getting it from intent, just like you did in MainActivity.

Comment: sorry I mean it  db.addContact(new Contact("Android", bmp)); .. like this right ?

Comment: You said that you would usually do it like this `db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte));` where imageInByte is a byte array, right? So, do the same thing after receiving the byte array from intent. Do not convert it back to bitmap. It would probably look like `db.addContact(new Contact("Android", byteArray));`